# Using mapply with a condition

Tags: r, function, matrix

I want to use mapply with a matrix using a function that contains an if like this:

```
dim_rf <- 10

rf <- matrix(runif(dim_rf*dim_rf),ncol=dim_rf)


fire_rf <- function(i,j) {
  if(rf[i,j+1] + rf[i+1,j] + rf[i,j-1] + rf[i-1,j]>1)
    rf[i,j] <-2
}

mapply(fire_rf, row(rf), col(rf)  )
```

but it gives an error

```
Error en if (rf[i, j + 1] + rf[i + 1, j] + rf[i, j - 1] + rf[i - 1, j] >  :
```

argument have zero length

how can I modify the function to make it work?

I am using this to do a simple model of fire percolation so it needs to be fast because the size of the matrix should be big 100 or 1000

Comment: You should add some conditions like `if(i > 1 & j > 1 & i < nrow(rf) & j < ncol(rf) )` But why do you try to do ?

Comment: When `j` or `i` is `1`, you try to subset `rf` using a zero as an index element. When `j` or `i` is equal to the maximum column or row number, the index also ends up being outside of `rf`. This ends up as an error in the `if` statement. So don't include those "edge" cases in the `mapply` iterations.

Comment: The point of your code is to generate a side-effect. As such, just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you debug your function:

```
fire_rf <- function(i,j) {
  print(paste(i, j))
  print(paste(rf[i,j+1], rf[i+1,j], rf[i,j-1], rf[i-1,j]))
}

R> mapply(fire_rf, row(rf), col(rf)) 
[1] "1 1"
[1] "0.431833460461348 0.723794676829129  "
[1] "2 1"
[1] "0.61886831978336 0.764425948029384  0.486255120486021"
[1] "3 1"
[1] "0.98786562983878 0.416759668383747  0.723794676829129"
[1] "4 1"
[1] "0.516932599013671 0.66259386530146  0.764425948029384"
[1] "5 1"
[1] "0.770237588090822 0.844016372924671  0.416759668383747"
[1] "6 1"
[1] "0.519682829733938 0.273759116884321  0.66259386530146"
[1] "7 1"
[1] "0.0957026474643499 0.32785635185428  0.844016372924671"
[1] "8 1"
[1] "0.380909610772505 0.164877543691546  0.273759116884321"
[1] "9 1"
[1] "0.509409713326022 0.614429801469669  0.32785635185428"
[1] "10 1"
Error in rf[i + 1, j] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: mapply -> <Anonymous> -> print -> paste
```

You see while you think you are passing in the arguments, sometimes you are not and sometimes you are passing more than is there. You need to think those 'i - 1', 'j - 1' and 'i + 1' and 'j + 1'. I would suggest you write a straight-forward loop if you really want to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that this is what you want. Your loop conditions were wrong allowing the algorithm to go out of bounds.

```
dim_rf <- 10
rf <- matrix(runif(dim_rf*dim_rf),ncol=dim_rf)
fire_rf <- function(i,j) {
    if((rf[i,j+1] + rf[i+1,j] + rf[i,j-1] + rf[i-1,j])>1)
         rf[i,j] <<-2
}
mapply(fire_rf, 2:(nrow(rf)-1), 2:(ncol(rf)-1))
```

Hope this helps. :)

PS. Also note that I changed the local assignment to a global assignment. If this is not what you want you can just change it back.